# How to get consecutive numbers but starting from 1 everytime the status changes in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to get Consecutive numbers for a table with people's information when they are absent but when the person is not absent for one month the count should start over.

```
Here is an example of what I am looking for.

| Prior Month Absent In a Row | Absent? | MonthDate | PersonId |
|              1              |  Yes    | 2022-01-01|    101   |
|              2              |  Yes    | 2022-02-01|    101   |
|              -              |   No    | 2022-03-01|    101   |
|              1              |  Yes    | 2022-04-01|    101   |
|              2              |  Yes    | 2022-05-01|    101   |
|              3              |  Yes    | 2022-06-01|    101   |
|              -              |   No    | 2022-01-01|    102   |
|              1              |  Yes    | 2022-02-01|    102   |
|              2              |  Yes    | 2022-03-01|    102   |
|              3              |  Yes    | 2022-04-01|    102   |
|              4              |  Yes    | 2022-05-01|    102   |
|              5              |  Yes    | 2022-06-01|    102   |
```

So basically for Each Person Id when they are Absent in a row it should count it but when the follow-up month is a No then it starts back at 1.

**I used a row partion by function, but that did not work well.**

Any suggestion or link would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select   case when grp is not null then row_number() over(partition by PersonId, grp order by MonthDate) end as prior_month_row
        ,Absent 
        ,MonthDate  
        ,PersonId
from
(
select   *
        ,case when Absent = 'Yes' then count(case when Absent = 'No' then 1 end) over(partition by PersonId order by MonthDate) end as grp
from     t
) t
order by PersonId, MonthDate
```

| prior_month_row | Absent | MonthDate | PersonId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes | 2022-01-01 | 101 |
| 2 | Yes | 2022-02-01 | 101 |
| null | No | 2022-03-01 | 101 |
| 1 | Yes | 2022-04-01 | 101 |
| 2 | Yes | 2022-05-01 | 101 |
| 3 | Yes | 2022-06-01 | 101 |
| null | No | 2022-01-01 | 102 |
| 1 | Yes | 2022-02-01 | 102 |
| 2 | Yes | 2022-03-01 | 102 |
| 3 | Yes | 2022-04-01 | 102 |
| 4 | Yes | 2022-05-01 | 102 |
| 5 | Yes | 2022-06-01 | 102 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jzF6GM6I)